# What is SparseVector in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, databricks

I am new to learning PySpark there using sparse vector what it does actually can someone explain easy way?

Below I have 3 categorical variables and it converted sparse vector I am not understanding what is `(2, {1: 1.0})`

```
InternetServiceCatVec=['Fiber optic','DSL','NO']

InternetServiceCatVec=SparseVector(2, {1: 1.0})
```

Comment: A sparse vector is a vector that contains mostly zeros, and so it stores only the positions and values of non-zero entries. The vector in your question should be equivalent to [0.0, 1.0], a sparse vector of length 2 with the element at index 1 equal to 1.0.